# Redirect to login page after a user is registered. laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel

How can I redirect to login page, after a user is registered on my web application with a message called "We have sent you a link on "user email". Please check your email to complete registration". By using laravel 5.5 version

**Note:** I have done the login and register by using Auth procress of laravel 5.5.

**RegisterController**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
use App\Events\UserReferred;
use App\Profile;
use App\Reflink;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Settings;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/verify/logout';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',

        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {

        $settings = Settings::first();

        $user = User::create([

            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
            'admin'=>0,
            'active'=>0,
            'membership_id'=>1,
            'membership_started'=>date('Y-m-d'),
            'membership_expired'=>'2020-12-31',
            'token'=>str_random(25),

        ]);

        Profile::create([

            'user_id'=>$user->id,
            'avatar'=>'uploads/avatars/default.jpg',
            'main_balance'=>$settings->signup_bonus,
        ]);

        Reflink::create([

            'user_id'=> $user->id,
            'link'=> str_random(4).$user->id.str_random(4),

        ]);

        $user->sendVerificationEmail();

        event(new UserReferred(request()->cookie('ref'), $user));

        session()->flash('message', 'Dear user your account create successful but not active. To active your account please check your email for verify code.');
        Session::flash('type', 'warning');
        Session::flash('title', 'Email Verify Required');


        return $user;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After the user is successfully registered a `Registered` event is fired. So in your `RegisterController` you can override the `registered` method and log out the user from there:

```
protected function registered( Request $request, $user )
{
    Auth::logout(); // don't forget to import the facade at the top of the class use Auth;
}
```

But a better approach is to use the `verified` middleware since you are using the verification option of Laravel.

So just surround your protected routes in a group:

```
Route::middleware([ 'auth', 'verified' ])->group(function () {
    // your routes here.
});
```

So even if the user is directly logged in after registration he would not be able to access any routes until he verifies his email.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to suggest that seeing as you are using Laravel 5.X you should consider upgrading to 5.7 as it comes with a built in email verification system as can be seen [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/verification) and with middleware functionalities to protect routes (`middleware('verified');`), events, views and post verification redirection.

Comment: @SamuelOshio you can upgrade Laravel on the fly just and run you the auth migration, just take a look at the migration guide.